# WPF Binding String Formatting Question

Tags: wpf, binding, formatting

This is probably pretty simple but I'm trying to take the value from an element in XML and put it in my DataGridTextColumn formatted to 3 decimal places but I can't get it to work...it just leaves it unformatted at like 20. Here is the line I am using. What am I doing wrong?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Avg" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[avg].Value, StringFormat=0:0.###}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your string format specification a bit.  This should work:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Avg" 
    Binding="{Binding Path=Element[avg].Value, StringFormat={}{0:0.###}}">
```

Note that `{}` is required at the beginning, since `{` causes the first part of the StringFormat specifier to be treated as a markup extension.

Comment: Actually, the exact same thing happens with this solution...it remains unformatted.

Comment: @novacara: What type is it being treated as?  Is it an int value or a string?  If so, the format string won't work, and you'd need to use an IValueConverter to make it a double or decimal value.

Comment: It is probably being treated as a string. Is there a way to specify the datatype in the xml or is my only option to make a class that implements IValueConverter?

Comment: @novacara: Value is always a string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx   You'll need to either turn this into something more meaningful, or use an IValueConverter to change this to a double.  The latter is probably nicest, as you could reuse it anywhere...

Comment: Alright, thanks for the nudge in the right direction. I am new to both XML and WPF.

Comment: @Reed: What does `Element[avg].Value` mean here? What is `avg`?  Is it index? Where does it come from?